# A non-serializable value was detected in the state in react native with expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, serialization, expo, redux-toolkit

When trying to login on iOS it works fine, but on android I keep getting the error

> A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path:
> `auth.loginErrorMessage`. Value:, [TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'status' of undefined],  Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this
> action type: auth//rejected.

I've done everything I found online even adding

```js
getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: {
    ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
  },
}),
```

to my store.ts.

I have the following in my authSlice.ts

```js
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/",
  async (
    { Username, password }: { Username: string; password: string },
    thunkApi
  ) => {
    try {
      const saveResponse = await authRequest.UserLogin(Username, password)

      // console.log( saveResponse.data._id)

      if (saveResponse.message === "success") {
        // console.log( saveResponse.data._id)
        const UserResponse = await authRequest.GetUserFull(saveResponse.data._id)

        console.log(UserResponse.status)
        if (UserResponse.status === 200) {
          let UserInfo: UserFull = UserResponse.data as UserFull

          return {
            allUserInformation: UserInfo,
          }
        } else {
          return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(
            "Something went wrong while getting your account"
          );
        }
      } else {
        console.log(saveResponse.data.data)
        switch (saveResponse.data.data) {
          case 0:
            return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(
              "A network error occur. Please check your connection"
            );
            case 403:
              return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(
                "Invalid Email or Password"
              );
            case 400:
              return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(
                "A bad request occured"
              );
            case 500:
              return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(
                "Something went wrong with our servers please try again later"
              );
            default:
              return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(
                "An error occured. Please try again later"
              );
        }
      }
    } catch (e: any) {
      console.log(e);
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(e);
    }
  }
)

const UserInformation = (
  state: AuthState,
  allUserInformation: UserFull
) => {
  
  state._id = allUserInformation._id
  return state;
};

const defaultAuth = (state: AuthState) => {
  
  state._id = null;
  return state;
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAuthStateTokens(
      state: AuthState,
      action: PayloadAction<{ _id: any; email: any }>
    ) {
      state._id = action.payload._id;
      state.email = action.payload.email;
    },
    clearAuthState(state: AuthState) {
      return initialState;
    },
    logOut(state: AuthState, action: PayloadAction<{ _id: any }>) {
      state._id = null
      localStorage.clear()
    },
    deleteAuthItem: (state) => ({
      ...state,
      user: {
        ...state.user,
        Username: "",
        _id: "",
        email: "",
        image: "",
        password: "",
        isActive: false,
        isVerified: false,
        role: "",
      },
      _id: "",
    }),
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(loginUser.pending, (state) => {
        // when login is pending
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.isError = false;
        state.loginErrorMessage = ""
        return state;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state: AuthState, action) => {
        // when login is unsuccessful
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.loginErrorMessage = action.payload as string;
        return state;
      })
      .addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        // when login is successful
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.loginErrorMessage = ""
        console.log("here")
        console.log(action.payload);
        const allUserInformation = action.payload?.allUserInformation as UserFull;
        return UserInformation(state, allUserInformation);
      })
      .addCase(LogoutUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;

        console.log("here")
        console.log(action.payload);
      
        return defaultAuth(state);
      });
    },
  }
);

export const {
  setAuthStateTokens,
  clearAuthState,
  deleteAuthItem
} = authSlice.actions;

export const authSelector = (state: RootState) => state.auth;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

and the request is given as

```
UserLogin: async (
Username: string,
password: string,
```

): Promise => {
const loginInfo = {
Username: Username,
password: password,
};

```
const body = loginInfo;
const res: LoginResponse = {
  status: 0,
  data: {},
  message: '',
};

try {
  const response = await axios.post(
    BASE_URL + '/users/login',
    body,
    {
      headers: {},
      method: 'POST',
    }
  );

  res.status = response.data.status;
  res.data = { ...response.data };
  res.message = response.data.message;

  return res.data;
} catch (err) {
  const errorResponse = err as { response?: { status: number; data: any }; message: string };

  if (errorResponse.response) {
    res.status = errorResponse.response.status;
    res.data = errorResponse.response.data;
  } else {
    res.status = 500;
    res.data = {};
  }
  res.message = errorResponse.message;

  return res.data;
}
```

},

EDIT
managed to rewrite the whole thing and discovered that I get a 500 network error on android but not ios
for android I'm connecting to my phone via hotspot but ios I'm using an emulator how do I work around this? I'm working off of my local database

Answer (score 0):

The only place I see in the code you've shared that is attempting to read a `status` property is in the `loginUser` action trying to read `UserResponse.status`. It seems this `UserResponse` object is undefined and throwing an error that is caught and returned via `thunkApi.rejectWithValue`. This is the entire error object.

A trivial solution is to first check that `UserResponse` is defined prior to accessing into it, and this is easily done using the Optional Chaining operator (`?.`), e.g. `UserResponse?.status`. The `if (UserResponse?.status)` expression will now safely fail falsey when `UserResponse` is null or undefined and the `else` branch is taken which returns a string value.

You may want to also guard other potentially null/undefined returned values.

Additionally, it appears you are expecting for returned rejection values to be strings, so perhaps you'll want to stringify the error or unpack the error's message value.

```js
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/",
  async (
    { Username, password }: { Username: string; password: string },
    thunkApi
  ) => {
    try {
      const saveResponse = await authRequest.UserLogin(Username, password);

      if (saveResponse?.message === "success") { // <-- null check/guard
        const UserResponse = await authRequest.GetUserFull(saveResponse.data._id);

        if (UserResponse?.status === 200) { // <-- null check/guard
          let UserInfo: UserFull = UserResponse.data as UserFull;

          return {
            allUserInformation: UserInfo,
          }
        } else {
          return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(
            "Something went wrong while getting your account"
          );
        }
      } else {
        switch (saveResponse.data.data) {
          ...
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      let error;
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        error = e.message; 
      } else {
        error = String(e);
      }
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(e);
    }
  }
);
```